# Satellite imagery from Google Earth into QGIS

Tags: qgis, google-earth

How can I copy satellite imagery as a raster file from Google Earth into QGIS for digitizing?

Answer (score 1):

Technically you can use [QuickMapServices](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/quick_map_services/) plugin.
But digitizing Google Earth violates service License.

Comment: Oh wow... I didn't know about the violation. I will try to get the QuickMapServices plugin and see how it works. Thank you.